# Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Tuple - Redis Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I am using **Spring Data Redis example**. In this example, simply trying to connect to the redis DB. Runnning the main method, I am getting below error.

**Spring Boot** version used is v **2.0.3.RELEASE** & **Redis version** is 2.4.5.

Code reference taken from : http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-data/spring-data-redis-example-spring-boot-redis-example and https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html. Can anybody please suggest what is wrong here ?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/javasampleapproach/redis/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Tuple
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1291) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1218) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Tuple
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Tuple
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConverters.<clinit>(JedisConverters.java:124) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<clinit>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.javasampleapproach.redis.config.RedisConfig.jedisConnectionFactory(RedisConfig.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javasampleapproach.redis.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b8821c.CGLIB$jedisConnectionFactory$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javasampleapproach.redis.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b8821c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d807fb2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.javasampleapproach.redis.config.RedisConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b8821c.jedisConnectionFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Tuple
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: redis.clients.jedis.Tuple
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
# Session store type.
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.flush-mode=on-save
spring.session.redis.namespace=spring:session

#Configuring the Redis Connection
# Redis server host.
spring.redis.host=localhost 

# Login password of the redis server.
spring.redis.password= 

# Redis server port.
spring.redis.port=6379
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**RedisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.javasampleapproach.redis")
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(){
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.javasampleapproach:spring-data-redis:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar:5.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.25.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.25.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.25.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.31:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.22:compile (optional)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have this dependency spring-boot-starter-data-redis at classpath?

Comment: @Maxim - Added maven dependency tree.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your example is referencing boot `1.5.X` which uses `Jedis`, by default `lettuce` is used in Boot `2.0` if you want to use `Jedis` you need to manually add the dependency. Additionally you can see that `Jedis` isn't on your classpath and `lettuce` is.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You might need to specify the dependency version. Alternatively you could just configure what you are attempting via `lettuce`.

Comment: You could still use Jedis, it is still supported for usage. http://www.baeldung.com/java-redis-lettuce has a walkthrough of the basic configuration.